# Pass Requests From Nginx to Local Thin Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, faye

I have nginx serving up my rails app, but I also have a separate 'thin' server running on another port to use with Faye (publish / subscribe gem).

So I believe that since all requests are going through nginx (right?), I can't just call myapp.com:9292 if the thin server is setup on that port, even if I use the myapp.com host rather than localhost for the thin server, because its not routed through nginx.

If I have the thin server running at 0.0.0.0:9292, what would I need to add to my nginx conf to route pings to myapp.com:9292 to 0.0.0.0:9292?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can - just call `example.com:9292` - , because Nginx is listening to port `80` only, and sometimes `443`

Unless you add another server block that listens to `9292` explicitly, the `example.com:9292` should pass directly to your 'thin' server

Comment: I have tried setting up my thin server this way, without that port being used by nginx, and the request just hangs. Using curl I just get 'you are being redirected' (by nginx I believe).

Comment: If you get a redirect then it isn't nginx, simple way to check it is turning nginx off and try the URL again, you'll find out it's still redirecting.